# Coeficientes mal calculados em Regressão Linear no R devido a NA´s

Tags: r

Esse é meu dataframe:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 
1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L), Month = c(10L, 11L, 
12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 
11L, 12L), Y.1 = c(8.00983263923528, 2.41267858341867, -0.701122343112104, 
-3.93438481559836, 1.61989462202274, -0.0837521649979607, -1.18856075379809, 
-5.79109166398385, -6.02656788564288, 3.57285443621284, 5.28086890954826, 
4.61968948421691, 1.6450358083769, 2.09679639676383, 3.13330926488653, 
7.03433470051535, 8.82984898471047, 6.35665464823924, -2.06916023327692, 
-6.80818412035661, -2.55840141236052, 5.93892137387166, 3.73139295521127, 
-2.43756307587375, -7.88332536927916, -11.1612368255376, -14.9073451470428, 
-3.39210451580797, -9.45264055248482, -6.71777033430725), X.1 = c(0.308656857874223, 
1.04586629806642, 0.861945545932596, 0.375970358978561, -0.347308458564966, 
-0.29159098146565, 0.658969566870815, 0.777325096646653, 0.819638059706351, 
0.14348380776068, 0.320980128297688, 0.422457840273038, 0.0753279027397413, 
-0.00412826834750302, -0.0306969460488249, 0.202590024491522, 
0.144588970489035, 0.299274727728394, 0.924086583854944, 0.903017497665926, 
0.964001122879932, 1.26678884737668, 1.24568369535494, 1.17738738727233, 
0.855877205956479, 0.778924677659654, 0.601219806786069, 0.967781164852632, 
1.10343758488876, 1.02401236754546), Y.2 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"5.33565675549722", "-0.477469962261498", "0.743881752912509", 
"0.946947439972276", "5.26357788348063", "6.20317011981397", 
"-3.44416166730468", "-4.98209173294852", "-4.17799392953961", 
"-1.60319913629998", "-2.07841411022162", "-3.07277915798255", 
"-6.81314462908097", "-8.99190729955144", "-6.41231440381122", 
"2.93695557772259", "7.71262044640592", "3.48797284502131", "-5.06072963216373", 
"-2.74288427337241", "3.50049327959275", "8.56226731314113", 
"12.0144762810381", "15.6527185635863", "4.17084966096979", "10.4311905060596", 
"7.6861205071862"), X.2 = c(0.288003451, 0.873662015, 0.874190316, 
0.36027826, -0.120926336, -0.276130722, 0.633675698, 0.849582846, 
0.778756432, 0.20203225, 0.221280623, 0.467109312, 0.07783831, 
-0.008749708, -0.023401276, 0.196393036, 0.18439037, 0.294919158, 
0.908446718, 0.922729322, 0.962361556, 0.74, 0.74, 0.77, 2.36, 
2.79, 1.76, 1.26, 1.48, 1.21)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Quando eu rodo a seguinte equação, por existir alguns NA´s o R faz o ajuste de deletar as 3 primeiras linhas de Y.1 e as 3 primeiras linhas de X.1. **Ele deveria deletar as 3 últimas linhas de X.1**:

```
summary(volcker.ini %>% lm(Y.1~X.1,data = .))
```

Como consigo fazer esse ajuste no codigo acima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deve haver qualquer coisa não standard com a sua sessão R.
Como se pode ler em `help("lm")`, na secção `Arguments` (minha ênfase):

> na.action
>
> a function which indicates what should happen when the data contain NAs.
>   The default is set by the na.action setting of options, and is na.fail if 
>   that is unset. **The ‘factory-fresh’ default is `na.omit`.** Another possible 
>   value is NULL, no action. Value `na.exclude` can be useful.

Isto significa que o comando `lm` vai omitir os valores `NA` a não ser que modifique o valor de `options()$na.action`. Esse valor pode ser verificado com

```
options()$na.action
#[1] "na.omit"
```

Se por acaso der outra coisa, basta correr o seguinte comando.

```
options(na.action = "na.omit")
```

No meu sistema é esse o valor, nunca o modifico. E quando corri o seu código deu tudo certo.

```
library(dplyr)

summary(volcker.ini %>% lm(Y.1 ~ X.1,data = .))
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = Y.1 ~ X.1, data = .)
#
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-14.1342  -4.0814   0.0258   4.5236  10.2769 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#(Intercept)    2.447      1.675   1.461   0.1552  
#X.1           -5.356      2.259  -2.371   0.0249 *
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 5.613 on 28 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.1672,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1375 
#F-statistic: 5.621 on 1 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.02486
```

Na citação acima diz que `na.exclude` pode ser útil. Veja a respetiva página `help("na.exclude")`, e se achar que é de fato útil, o código modificado será

```
summary(volcker.ini %>% lm(Y.1 ~ X.1,data = ., na.action = na.exclude))
```

E já agora, porque não dividir essa instrução em duas, uma para atribuir o valor de `lm` e outra para o `summary`?

```
modelo <- volcker.ini %>% lm(Y.1 ~ X.1,data = ., na.action = na.exclude)
summary(modelo)
```

Mais tarde poderá querer `coef(modelo)` ou outros valores como resíduos.

Finalmente, para isso não voltar a acontecer, veja se tem um ficheiro chamado `.RData` (isto não é uma extensão, é o nome completo do ficheiro) e se tiver remova-o.